# how to loop by each value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Below is the code where I want to filter in the data frame through the country list in a loop. how to pass that value in the Owning country filter?

This is my Code :

```
countrylist= ['Italy','Germany']
for country in countrylist:
        dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['Owning_Country'] == ]
```

Thanks

Comment: `dataframe['Owning_Country'] == country`? If that's not what you meant, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
countrylist= ['Italy','Germany']

for country in countrylist:

df= df[df['Owning_Country'] == country]
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have to use sleep from time module i guess.

```html
import time

countrylist= ['Italy','Germany']
for country in countrylist:
    print(country)
    time.sleep(1)
    dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['Owning_Country'] == country]
```

maybe sommeone can provide a better way but as so far this is the simplest way.